# 90/180 in for Guadeloupe

Tags: schengen, 90-180-visa-rules, guadeloupe

If what I've read is correct, Guadeloupe is part of France and EU but not part of Schengen.  However, they also have a 90/180 rule for US citizens.  So it seems (can't imagine anyone wanting to) you could go back and forth between Schengen and Guadeloupe indefinitely (with a transition day somewhere else to avoid counting the travel day in both).

Am I misinterpreting something?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're legally correct, but if you actually tried to do that, at some point, some border guard would notice and stop letting you in. [comment not an answer because I haven't actually researched it]

Comment: I expect the immigration officer would query how you manage to shuttle between the two **as a tourist** without working to support yourself. Being able to do that is theoretically possible, but unlikely.

Comment: I don’t particularly want to do THAT, but I was quite comfortable in twenty countries on my retirement income for four years.  Only once (entering UK) was I asked about finances.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about the general case (Guadeloupe / Schengen Area), but **for the specific case of mixing stays in Guadeloupe with stays in metropolitan France**:

- Note that the rule for Guadeloupe is not 90/180 but 3 months out of 6, starting at any entry into any of the territories concerned. Close, but not exactly the same in some edge cases.
- **The 3 months out of 6 rule includes metropolitan France**, so you would not be able to go back and forth between Guadeloupe and metropolitan France. And since many of the flights to/from Guadeloupe go through France, even if during the "alternating months" you do not stay in metropolitan France, you would need to be careful with your transit days in France. Of course, the lack of stamps while travelling between France and the rest of the Schengen area may complicate things a fair amount.
- This includes many of the other French overseas territories in the area and elsewhere (but not all). So likewise, it's not possible to spend 3 months in Guadeloupe, 3 months in Saint Martin…

References:

- [Arrêté du 26 juillet 2011 relatif aux documents et visas exigés pour l'entrée des étrangers sur le territoire de la Guadeloupe, la Guyane, la Martinique, La Réunion et de la collectivité de Saint-Pierre-et-Miquelon](https://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/loda/id/JORFTEXT000024403998/):

> Article 3
>
> (...) sont dispensés du visa prévu à ce même article les étrangers mentionnés à l'annexe II du présent arrêté, dans les limites qu'elle fixe.
>
> (...)
>
> Annexe II
>
> Modifié par Arrêté du 28 décembre 2020 - art. 1
>
> 1. Liste des pays ou des entités administratives dont les titulaires de passeport sont dispensés de visa pour entrer sur le territoire de la Guadeloupe, la Guyane, la Martinique, La Réunion et de la collectivité de Saint-Pierre-et-Miquelon afin d'y effectuer **des séjours dont la durée n'excède pas trois mois par période de six mois sur l'ensemble du territoire défini au premier alinéa de l'article L. 111-2 du code de l'entrée et du séjour des étrangers et du droit d'asile**, sauf accord de circulation plus favorable, et limites à cette dispense

(emphasis mine)

- First paragraph of [Article L111-2 of Code de l'entrée et du séjour des étrangers et du droit d'asile](https://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/codes/article_lc/LEGIARTI000037399612/)

> (...) le présent code régit l'entrée et le séjour des étrangers **en France métropolitaine, en Guadeloupe, en Guyane, en Martinique, à Mayotte, à La Réunion, à Saint-Pierre-et-Miquelon, à Saint-Barthélemy et à Saint-Martin**.

(emphasis mine)

Comment: (+1) I have not looked into the interaction with the rules for overseas territories but the rule for the Schengen area (and therefore metropolitan France) *is* 90 days out of a 180-day period. I would remove the “but for metropolitan France”, it's confusing and somewhat inaccurate.

Comment: @Relaxed I updated the text slightly to make it clearer that I'm talking about the Guadeloupe/metropolitan France mix (as opposed to Guadeloup/any Schengen country), not stays (just) in metropolitan France.

Comment: I specifically said Schengen, not “France,” but I wasn’t aware there were special rules there.  On the other hand, France supposedly also has a 180-day agreement with USA, which further complicates things.

Comment: @WGroleau Just wanted to emphasise the fact that (as too often, especially at interesting intersections of the terribly complex European Venn diagram), the rules are not necessarily uniform, as one may mistakenly think that rules would be the same for the whole of the Schengen Area (including metropolitan France). I **think** that it would be OK for any other Schengen Area country, with the caveat above that you need to be careful about transit time through metropolitan France on your way to/from Guadeloupe.

Comment: Enjoying the interesting intricacies, although I don’t plan on doing that to-and-fro.  Just occurred to me when I noticed that the “special territories” section of a Wikipedia article on the visa requirements for US citizens is missing Guadeloupe.