# French overseas territories and Schengen

Tags: schengen, france

I'm no longer traveling, but I'm still curious about some of the interesting rules.

Rather than edit [90/180 in for Guadeloupe](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/163351/90-180-in-for-guadeloupe/163353#163353), I'll ask a new more general question.

Since French overseas territories are not part of Schengen, could someone in a country subject to the 90/180 rule avoid returning his/her home country by moving between French-speaking areas?  Because the day of travel counts on both ends, it would require at least three countries/areas.

Please, don't waste words accusing me of anything—I'm just curious about the rules.  I have family in USA, so I am not interested in leaving permanently.  (Not that our politics haven't made it cross my mind).  Finances are also irrelevant as is the fact that the whims of border officials might foil the plans of this hypothetical hobo.

Comment: I wonder if this question fits better on Expatriates, as each of the stays will be more than just a travel visit, people over there may know better about those longer stays.

Comment: Kind of on the fence.  Don't know my hypothetical hobo's motives.  He's definitely expatriate in the sense of being permanently out of the country of his birth.  But he isn't permanently settling anywhere.  I think expatriates is more for people who do want to settle somewhere else.

Comment: No, it is for people who stay months or longer.